# Windows server 2016 with Shibboleth 3.6

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, shibboleth, idp

I am setting up SSO for my users on a Windows Server 2016 with Shibboleth 3.6 as an IDP. I have claimed the domain in my SP settings and have the Idp metadata uploaded on the SP as well the SP metadata saved on my Shibboleth/ metadata folder. When I try to sign in with my domain on the SP, it redirects but then the webpage says "This site can't be reached" It seems to me that the Idp URL is not accessible. How can I host my Idp page on the Windows Server machine? I have the Apache Tomcat 9.0 installed on the system as well and would like to use it for the IDP page.

Answer (score 0):

I think your browser (PC) can not connect to IdP web page.
Maybe DNS problem or IdP server port not be open.